# How to calculate massive data in JAVA efficiently

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network

I want to train my data for Learning Vector Quantization in 2d array which is contain massive double type data, for example: inputVector[50][480], and the code is like this

```
public void TrainLVQ(int maxEpoch, double minLearningRate){
    euclideandistance = new double[numberofcluster];
    System.out.print("Training LVQ");
    int epoch = 0;
    while(epoch <= maxEpoch || learnigRate >= minLearningRate)
        epoch = epoch +1;
        for(int k=0;k<numberofinput;k++){
            //Get the winning neuron
            winningneuron = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<numberofcluster;i++){
                euclideandistance[i] = ComputeEuclideanDistance(bobot[i],inputVector[k]);
                if(i!=0){
                    if(euclideandistance[i]<euclideandistance[winningneuron]){
                        winningneuron = i;
                    }
                }
                //System.out.println(euclideandistance[i]);
            }
            if(targetcluster[k] == winningneuron){
                for(int i=0;i<inputdimension;i++){
                    bobot[winningneuron][i] += learnigRate * (inputVector[k][i] - bobot[winningneuron][i]);
                }
            }
            else{
                for(int i=0;i<inputdimension;i++){
                    bobot[winningneuron][i] = bobot[winningneuron][i] - (learnigRate * (inputVector[k][i] - bobot[winningneuron][i]));
                }
            }

            //System.out.println("Winner:"+winningneuron);
            //Update the winning neuron
        }
        learnigRate = learnigRate * minLearningRate;
        System.out.print(".");  
        //System.out.println("Learn Rate:"+learnrate);
    }
}
```

I know calculating like this can cause program not responding because the process is too much and too long, is there any efficient way to make the process lighter?

Comment: I believe this type of questions is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: 50*480 is all but massive; but this is still *tiny* data. It may seem large for doing it by hand, but 200kb is not "large" by any modern means since DOS.

Comment: You may want to use [Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) to replace some of your inner loops and inside your ComputeEuclideanDistance function. But before anything, don't forget to profile your code.